# How to build Junit tests for a Comparator.comparing?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

After several times trying to solve a sort problem, the only way who worked was using a implementation like this:

```java
List<Product> productsList = new ArrayList<>();

productsList = myRepository.queryResult();

productsList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Product::getPrice));
```

Basicaly, this code take price attibute as key to sort values in ascending mode.

However, my problem is to build a test for Comparator code.

I had tried to create two objects and sort them to compare but not worked:

```java
@Test
public void getComparisonProducts{
    List<Product> productsList = new ArrayList<>();
    Product product = new Product();
    product.setPrice(11.22);

    productsList.add(product)

    Product product2 = new Product();
    product2.setPrice(22.11);

    productsList.add(product2)

    Comparator<Product> comparator = Comparator.comparing(Product::getPrice);

    productsList.sort(comparator);

    assertEquals(comparator.compare(productsList.get(0), productsList.get(1)), -1);
}
```

Runing the test, I have this failure:

[image]

Some Google's researchs not helped yet.

Comment: "but not worked" is not a problem description. Create a test that creates a predefined `List<Product>` with specific prices. Please show your attempt.

Comment: True and sorry @f1sh. I updated the question with my test case and the returned failure. Tranks!

Comment: Either there's a null Product or `getPrice()` is returning null.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code, you are setting the price for `product` twice, and not at all for `product2`…

Comment: Thanks! Really was a mistake during copy and paste the commands but not solve the problem.

Comment: You should not have the same NullPointerException failure any more...